# How can i insert a text beside the navigation at the header

Tags: css, header, navigation

Which code do i need to type to make a text or a logo on my header nav?

I want my text or logo on the right line with my navi just on the left site of the nav position.

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 98%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html"><strong>H</strong>ome</a>
    <a href="mywork.html"><strong>M</strong>yWork</a>
    <a href="about.html"><strong> A</strong>bout</a>
    <a href="contact.html"><strong> C</strong>ontact</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: i want it left for my nav position,  
text = Khan Portfolio

Comment: I don't think I would use `position: fixed;` on the `<nav>` element. Maybe move it out to `<header>`, kind of depends on what your objective is. Are you trying to center the `<nav>`? What is the purpose of using fixed positioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a few liberties with the layout, making a few assumptions about what you might have intended.

- I applied the styles you had on `<nav>` to `<header>`, seemed to make more sense that way.
- I used absolute positioning on the text/logo so that it would be taken out of the normal document flow and not affect the layout of other elements.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
nav > a {
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Khan Learner</h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html"><strong>H</strong>ome</a>
    <a href="mywork.html"><strong>M</strong>y Work</a>
    <a href="about.html"><strong> A</strong>bout</a>
    <a href="contact.html"><strong> C</strong>ontact</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: and what if i want the " Khan Learner " follows the navigation bar. 
right now my navi follows when i scrool downs, but the header dosent

Comment: @KhanLearner that's a separate question from the one you asked. Also, your question isn't very clear.

Comment: okay i try to explain better now. 
i got this navbar at my top header but i want to add a logo/image/text beside my nav. 

So if i have the nav at right corner, how can i add another sign logo/image/text at left corner, just like this site i just linket below,  


http://clapat.ro/themes/villar-wordpress/villar_portfolio/john-berwanger/

Comment: @KhanLearner all the solutions provided to you have added a logo/image/text beside your nav, two to the left side and one to the right side. The main difference between the site you linked to and what has been proved in answers, based on your code, is the navigation is centered in the header instead of aligned to the right of the header. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear but I think this is what you're looking for:

```css
nav{ 
        display: inline-block;
        position: fixed;
        width: 98%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: (red);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        z-index: 99;
        text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<head>        
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content=" min portfolio ">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<header>
    <a id="logo" href="index.html"><strong>L</strong>ogo</a>
    <nav>
    
    <a href="index.html"><strong>H</strong>ome</a>
    <a href="mywork.html"><strong>M</strong>yWork</a>
    <a href="about.html"><strong> A</strong>bout</a>
    <a href="contact.html"><strong> C</strong>ontact</a>
    </nav>
    
    
    
    </header>    
<style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
nav{ 
  position: fixed;
  width: 98%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: (red);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
}
span{
  display:block;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html"><strong>H</strong>ome</a>
    <a href="mywork.html"><strong>M</strong>yWork</a>
    <a href="about.html"><strong> A</strong>bout</a>
    <a href="contact.html"><strong> C</strong>ontact</a>
    <span>Khan Portfolio</span>
  </nav>
</header>
```